# understanding the execution flow in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Being new to python, confused with the flow of execution:

To elaborate I am stating the below examples:

**Example 1:**

```
def hello():
    print("hello world")
    python()

def python():
    print("testing main")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello()

**output :**
    hello world
    testing main
```

NOTE : I am aware of usage of **__name__ == "__main__".**

**Example 2:**

```
python()

def python():
    print("testing main")

**output**
File "main_flow.py", line 2, in <module>
python()
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
```

As far as I know python executes the program in sequential manner(correct me if I am wrong), hence in Example 2 it is not able to find the method python() when it encounters it.

My confusion is why in example 1 the similar error has not occured, what is the flow of execution in this scenario.

Comment: Because in the first example, `python` is not executed before it is defined, in the second example, it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit 1**:
When you call a custom function in python it must know where it is located in the file. We use `def function_name():` to define the location of functions we use in our scripts. We must call `def function_name():` before we call `function_name()`, otherwise the script won't know about `function_name()` and will raise an exception (function not found error).

By running `def function_name():` it only lets the script know there is a function called `function_name()` but it doesn't actually run the code inside `function_name()` until you call it.

While in your second example you call `python()` before the script has reached `def python()`, so it doesn't know what `python()` is yet.

The **Example 1** order is:

```
1.    def hello(): # Python now knows about function hello()
5.        print("hello world")
6.        python()

2.    def python(): # Python now knows about function python()
7.        print("testing main")

3.    if __name__ == "__main__":
4.       hello()
```

The **Example 2** order is:

```
1.    python()    # Error because Python doesn't know what function python() is yet

-     def python(): # Python doesn't reach this line because of the above error
-         print("testing main")
```

The **Example 2** solution would be:

```
1.     def python(): # Python now knows about function python()
3.         print("testing main")

2.     python()
```

**Edit 2:**
To reiterate **Example 1** from the scripts point of view:

```
def hello(): 
def python(): 
if __name__ == "__main__":
hello() 
print("hello world")
python()
print("testing main")
```

This is the order the script will see and run each line of code. So clearly the script knows about `python()` as the def is called on line #2, and `python()` is called on line number #6.

It appears you do not understand what scope means when it comes to defines. Read up about it. The scope of a function is not executed during a def, it is only executed when the function is called.

Comment: See edit. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: I agree and understood the point, "We must call def function_name(): before we call function_name(), otherwise the script won't know about function_name() and will raise an exception (function not found error)." But the same is happening in example 1 as well,  that function python() is called before it is defined, why the same error has not occurred in this case. Don't mind for asking the same question again.

Comment: Look at the order at which **Example 1** is called, it is clear that the order is **1.** `def hello():`, **2.** `def python():`, **3.** `if __name__ == "__main__":`, **4.** `hello()` etc.

I have already written the order in my solution, it should be pretty clear if you follow the order.

Comment: thanks for explaining in detail, true, I was in a different impression about the scope..

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** about `__name__ == '__main__'` but because the function call in your second example is executed **before** the function is defined.

Your first example executes the function `python` **after** all functions are defined because `hello` is called after the function definitions (so there is no name error)!

If you put `hello()` between the definitions you would get the error again:

```
def hello():
    print("hello world")
    python()

hello()

def python():
    print("testing main")
```

gives:

```
hello world 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-21db1c6bfff8> in <module>()
      3     python()
      4 
----> 5 hello()
      6 
      7 def python():

<ipython-input-7-21db1c6bfff8> in hello()
      1 def hello():
      2     print("hello world")
----> 3     python()
      4 
      5 hello()

NameError: name 'python' is not defined
```